# Monorepo in GitLab - Java/Spring:boot/MVN - CI/CD issue - How to run jobs in order

Tags: maven, gitlab, devops, cicd, monorepo

I'm a DevOps student and I have a project to run and I've stuck on something, I hope I can solve it with your help.

On our project we use Java monorepo which means we have multiple services in one repository, each in its own directory, six in total.

I have one main CI/CD scenario file .gitlab-ci.yml and dedicated scenario files for each microservice in its directory.

```
    /
    .gitlab-ci.yml
    /EurecaServer/.gitlab-ci.yml
    /ApiGateway/.gitlab-ci.yml
    /UserService/.gitlab-ci.yml
    /DepositService/.gitlab-ci.yml
    /CreditService/.gitlab-ci.yml
    /InfoService/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

In the root scenario file .gitlab-ci.yml I'm using 'include' to collect all microservices .gitlab-ci.yml files.

```yaml
    stages:
     - docker-compose-start
     - test
     - build
     - deploy

    include:
     - EurekaServer/.gitlab-ci.yml
     - ApiGateway/.gitlab-ci.yml
     - UserService/.gitlab-ci.yml
     - DepositService/.gitlab-ci.yml
     - CreditService/.gitlab-ci.yml
     - InfoService/.gitlab-ci.yml

    docker-compose-start:
     stage: docker-compose-start
     tags:
       - shell-runner-1
    script:
       - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --force-recreate -d
```

In those microservices scenario files I'm using 'needs' to make stages follow in order. First I have a test stage, then build and deploy at the end.

When the pipeline starts (from the root .gitlab-ci.yml), every microservice scenario runs randomly which fails in some stages build and deploy.

Is there a possibility to make separated microservices scenario files .gitlab-ci.yml runs in specific order? First - EurecaServer, second - ApiGateway, etc.

[gitlab pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTvis.png) <--picture is here, sorry not enough reputation.

My fellow students advised me to try to make one job to build all six microservices and another to deploy all ms's but I'm not quite sure if it is the right way because I want to see every microservice job specifically to make troubleshooting more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since `needs` is already used to make the jobs follow the order of test, build, then deploy, stages are not needed for that.

Rather, `stages` can be used to specify the order to run microservices like so:

```yaml
stages:
 - docker-compose-start
 - EurekaServer
 - ApiGateway
```

And the jobs can include their stages like `stage:ApiGateway`.